# Compiler command line for C# projects

Tags: c#, .net, csc

Visual Studio shows the exact command line use to compiler and link a C++ project under Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line and Linker ->Command Line, but, I was not able to find similar property page for C# projects.

Does any know what's the best way to find out the csc.exe command line arguments used to compile a C# project

Comment: That's not the exact C++ command line, only the buildlog.htm has it.  The C# one is in the Output window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `csc.exe` directly, I would recommend looking at `msbuild` instead.  With `msbuild`, you just have to run `msbuild yourProject.csproj` to compile it.

Also, per [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ed_maurer/archive/2008/06/11/a-tale-of-two-compilers.aspx), the `csc.exe` command line you see in the output window isn't really being used.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio, go to Debug->Windows->Output. When you compile your project this window will show you the commands it is using to compile your code, including the CSC command(s).

Be sure chose the "Show output from: Build" in the option dropdown in the Output window.

Comment: Does not make sense, why the debug output view will contain the compiler command line. The build output does not contain the command line.

Comment: It absolutely does my friend! Chose the "Show output from: Build" in the option.

Comment: Hmm you might be right, but, this is the output of build window for my test project. Do I need to enable some flag in Build config somewhere? 



------ Rebuild All started: Project: Tests, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
  Tests -> c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Tests\Tests\bin\Debug\Tests.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Hmm I'm using VS2008, not 2010. I guess it's different. You should use @David's answer, then. Here's my sample output:        ------ Rebuild All started: Project: Blah, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /errorreport: {etc etc}
Compile complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
Blah -> E:\Blah\bin\Debug\Blah.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 2):

See [MSDN: Command-line Building With csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

Comment: Already did that, need to debug some weird problem where I am able to compile a C# file through IDE, but, while compiling it from command line I get an invalid executable. In anycase, I think it would be good to have access to exact command line that's used to build a project. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2010 go to

Tools->Options->Project and Solutions->Build and Run

change "MSBuild  project build output verbosity" to something less filtering than Minimal (for example "Normal"). There will be a lot more talk in the Build Output window after this and you should be able to see the actual command line of how CSC was invoked.

Comment: Very useful info. This should be the accepted answer.